# How to display name on a column chart itself in SSRS, not on a legends

Tags: t-sql, ssrs

How can I display legends name on a column chart itself in SSRS?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you cannot do that. But, I came across something similar answered on the forum already. You can achieve a similar effect by following the steps in the link below.

Please go through the below link and check if it might be useful to you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9503789/2818351

Credits to the original author who answered the question.